# How to set button text using resource file

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have created resource file under Test Project but not under App_GlobalResources.How can i set button text using resource file.
For eg:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="<%:TestProject.TestResource.Test%>" />
```

When i use above code i am getting blank text in the button.

**Note - I don't want to set text at code behind.How can i achieve this at aspx file.**

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 15):

Assuming your Resourcesfile is called:

```
/App_GlobalResources/TestResource.resx
```

And the resource string `Test`, this should work:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: TestResource, Test %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Resource files say you have something like this

`MyButtonText` ------>  `WhateverText`

Then you can set the Text as follows

```
<asp:Button ID="mybtn" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:MyButtonText%>"
```

**[Refer to Sample Article](http://www.aspspider.com/resources/Resource1245.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @freebird.Let's say we have two resource files under Test Project ->TestResources -> TestRes1,TestRes2.TestRes1 -> MyButtonText -> Text1, TestRes2 -> MyButtonText -> Text2. If i use above code which button text it will take Or else is there any specific way of mentioning the resource file full path?

Comment: @Beginner You need to set Text for the button in both the resource files as ID Value such as `ID--> MyButtonText`  `Value-->Lang1Text`  `ID-->MyButtonText` `Value-->Lang2Text`.

Comment: @Beginner It will take by defult `en-US` as default text.

Comment: Sorry i didnot get you. Can i set something like this <asp:Button ID="mybtn" runat="server" Text="<$Resouces:TestProject.TestResources1.MyButtonText" /> <asp:Button ID="mybtn1" runat="server" Text="<$Resouces:TestProject.TestResources2.MyButtonText" />. But this is not working.

Comment: @Beginner Which Languages you want to translate to?

Comment: @Beginner Please refer to the link I added in my answer.It might help you.

Comment: @freebird.Thanks for the link. But in the example they are adding resources in App_GlobalResources. But in my case i don't have resource files in App_GlobalResources. I have created custom project for resource files. and i want to use that custom project resource files in my button text.Please let me know if i am missing something\

Answer (score 0):

The best way to provide resources for your pages would be using custom resource provider in your case because you dont want to use App_GlobalResources, and store all the resource data in Viewdata or Session data in codebehind and retrieve them and associate that to your button text in your aspx page.

Here is an msdn article on it (this article also explains to use resources from external assembly):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx

Hope that helps.